# Своя сборка yandex Алисы

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, яндекс-алиса

кто-то делает свою сборку linux, а вот мне нужна своя сборка Алисы от Яндекса. Я хочу взять текущую официальную версию Алисы, добавить в нее свой функционал и использовать в своих проектах.
Эти проекты будут только для личного использования, так что с copywriting проблем не будет.
Вот функционал который я собираюсь добавить(это не весь функционал, это просто для примера):
1)NLP. Например: когда Алиса спрашивает включить ли музыку, Алиса классифицирует ответ юзера(к классам да или нет)
2) Хочу чтобы Алиса называла меня повелителем:)
Это только малая часть желаемого функционала.
Как это сделать(сборку Алисы, функционал я добавлю сам)?

Comment: Если исходники где-то выложены, то можете попытаться. Но что-то я сомневаюсь. Сделайте лучше свой модуль, speech recognition нынче не такая уж большая проблема.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я плохо разбираюсь в Машинном Обучении, а готовые модули(Ex: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) меня по-всякому ограничивают(В модуле на который я вам скинул ссылку, нельзя распознавать речь из mp3 файла более 2 минут. )

Comment: основу можите посмотреть тут: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YeS755SPSI8

Comment: @CrazyElf, Если с speech recognition всё понятно, то как внедрить nlp в голосового ассистента. Например: когда голосовой ассистент спрашивает включить ли музыку, он классифицирует ответ юзера(к классам да или нет). Как это сделать? Может какой-то модуль?

Comment: @kali_xyyali Но если у вас есть speech recognition вам от него придут слова - ну вы и посмотрите есть там "да" или "нет", например. Если ничего знакомого не найдёте - придётся переспросить.

Comment: @kali_xyyali А если вы про более сложные случаи типа "давай включай!" == "да" - ну, тут уже надо думать. Модулей то полно, вопрос на чём именно их учить, на каких примерах.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я про да== давай включай... Я пишу код на python. Может что-то посоветуете(например модуль, или хотя бы что гуглить) Смотрел разные видео про nlp, ответа не нашёл.

Comment: @CrazyElf, датасет я найду. С остальной реализацией поможете?

Comment: @kali_xyyali В данном случае боюсь вам придётся самому список синонимов согласия подбирать, что-то ничего в голову не приходит как это можно методами машинного обучения сделать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, Список синонимов я подберу, вы потом поможете с созданием и обучением модели?

Comment: @kali_xyyali Да я не понимаю что там учить, там просто сравнить результат распознавания голоса с конкретными фразами )  Там нет предмета для машинного обучения кроме собственно модуля распознавания речи, который будет готовый видимо